# Как правильно сделать редирект на javascript после ответа от сервера?

Tags: javascript, html, jwt

Как правильно сделать чтобы после отправки данных на сервер(java) и получения от сервера токен оно сразу добавило токен в локальное хранилище, затем сделало со страницы логина на другую (для авторизированных пользователей) редирект , включая в заголовок этот токен 'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+jwt (чтобы распознало на другой странице как авторизированного пользователя) ?

Вот пока что имеется кривое :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form id="loginForm">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn">
        </form>

        <a href="/auth/registration">Зарегистрироваться</a>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("loginForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            const formData = {
                email: document.getElementById("email").value,
                password: document.getElementById("password").value
            };

            fetch('/auth/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData)
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.jwt) {
                        localStorage.setItem('Authorization', data.jwt);
                        window.location.href = '/user/yes'; // Редирект на /user/yes
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        });

        function makeAuthorizedRequest(url, jwt) {
            const headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Authorization','Bearer '+jwt);

            fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: headers
            })
                .then(response => {
                    // Обработка ответа от сервера
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        }

        
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            const jwt = localStorage.getItem('Authorization');
            if (jwt) {
                makeAuthorizedRequest('/user/yes', jwt);
            }
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Не видел чтоб страницы грузились с bearer. Только апи

Comment: headers Authorization такой, так должен токен начинаться , и нужно чтобы этот заголовок после авторизации постоянно передавались потом так именно